# How to align a whole content to up of page

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

How can I align a whole page content to beginning of page? I would like to prevent such situations, where there are huge distances between elements like lists or paragraphs (evenly distributed elements) because the next item didn't fit on this page:

[image]

Comment: Well, a quick fix could be to add `\raggedbottom` in your preamble.  With the little information you provide in your question, it’s difficult to say more.

Comment: It would also be possible that you have some strange code activated in your document, which is creating this spacing mess. Hard to say. But, `\raggedbottom`  should be a good start.

Comment: Could be a tabular or figure, that's not floating, or bad float placement. Without seeing the code it's hard to guess what's at fault here.

Comment: Thanks `\raggedbottom` resolved problem. On the next page I had big plot from `tikzpicture` and this element didn't fit on this page from screen.